# typescript + lodash - cannot find module

Tags: javascript, typescript, lodash

I'm trying to get typescript and lodash to work in my app but when I run

> *tsc --module commonjs lodash-test.ts*

Im always  getting

> lodash-test.ts(2,20): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'lodash'.

This still produces a lodash-test.js file

```
"use strict";
//lodash test that will be injected in index.html
var _ = require("lodash");
console.log('This is your lodash ts file');
console.info(_.chunk(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 2));
```

Now when I run my index.html file in my browser, I'm getting

> lodash-test.js:3 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

on line 3 of the file.

*Index.html* file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>    
<head>
    <meta charset=utf-8 />
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/lodash/dist/lodash.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lodash-test.js"></script>    
</head>    
<body>
    <h3>Hey</h3>
</body>    
</html>
```

I have the lodash type definition in my typings folder. How can I make sure that Typescript can find this lodash/index.d.ts file? Also how can I fix the "require is not defined" error?

This is my file structure:

[image]

thanks for the help

Comment: Try to import `d.ts` typings file with a `/// <reference path="" />` command on top of your TypeScript file. Because for now, `tsc` has now clue that you have typings files. So it can't find it.

Comment: @Blackus I have changed my lodash-test.ts to http://imgur.com/n8Kp5pv and it produced what is on the right side of the image. I've also removed the <script> lodash library in my index.html. I am still getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

`var _ = require("lodash");` is not necessary with the way you are loading your scripts.

In your `<head>` you have the line:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/lodash/dist/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

which loads `_` into the global namespace. `require("lodash")` is a module loader that loads lodash at runtime.

*So*:

A) remove the `require` statement and just use the var `_` as though it were already loaded (since it is). You may have to do some tricky stuff with the `declare` keyword to get `tsc` to not complain that `_` is undefined.

B) Remove the `<script>` for lodash in your `<head>` and setup `require` properly so that it knows what `"lodash"` is. Otherwise you **might** be able to simple do something like `var _ = require('bower_components/lodash/dist/lodash.min');`